# Importing data via a `require` statement seems to "memorize" the previous value imported by that statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this in file `data.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    data: {
        value: 42
    }
};
```

I am importing that in file `test.js`:

```
function load(fileName) {
    const {data} = require(fileName);
    data.value += 5;
    return data;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    console.log(load("data.js"));
```

When I execute `node test.js`, the printout is:

```
{ value: 47 }
{ value: 52 }
{ value: 57 }
{ value: 62 }
{ value: 67 }
```

I expected `{ value: 42 }` to be printed in every iteration, but I understand that probably `data` references the object returned from `require(fileName)`, so changing `data.value` impacts the contents of that object.

But what I don't understand is, why the `require` statement isn't executed "from scratch", i.e., on the **original** input file.

Of course, I can work around this by changing `data.js` into a properly formatted JSON file, and then load that file using something like:

```
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileAsync(data.json));
```

But I would like to get a deeper understanding of why using a `require` statement is inappropriate in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Require is for modules. You wouldn't want to have modules loaded from scratch each time they are required, because it would be a waste of resources and also it would mean you couldn't have modules with state. (the same module may be required hundreds of times in a project)

Comment: By the way, you could make your module export a _function_ instead that returns a fresh object every time and then import and call the function to get such an object.

Comment: @CherryDT: Thank you for the suggestion. How would that function behave any differently though? It would return a reference to an object in the exact same manner, am I wrong?

Comment: But since that object would be scoped to the function invocation it would be a new object every time.

Comment: @CherryDT: Yup, just verified that. Awesome, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because of the cache feature of the `require()` function. The `require()` function caches module and every next time returns the cached version.
Each module is only loaded and evaluated the first time it is required since any subsequent call of `require()` will simply return **the cached version**. This should be clear by looking at follows:

```
//D:\\backend node\\backend-projects\\test\\test2.js file
function load(fileName) {
    console.log(`cache 
    ${JSON.stringify(require
     .cache["D:\\backend node\\backend-projects\\test\\test2.js"]
    .children)}`) //here I print the children property of the require.cache object
    const {data} = require(fileName);
   
    data.value += 5;
    return data;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++)

    console.log(load("./test.js"));
```

For simulation here, I use a simple approach, every time when load function invokes, it prints cached data for me so I can see what happens when `require` function invokes, so this operation returns the following result:

```
cache
    [] // there is no cached data 
//because require function is invoked first time, it returns original data
{ value: 47 }
cache 
    [{"id":"D:\\backend node\\backend-projects\\test\\test.js","path":"D:\\backend node\\backend-projects\\test","exports":{"data":{"value":47}},"filename":"D:\\backend node\\backend-projects\\test\\test.js","loaded":true,"children":[],"paths":["D:\\backend node\\backend-projects\\test\\node_modules","D:\\backend node\\backend-projects\\node_modules","D:\\backend node\\node_modules","D:\\node_modules"]}]
{ value: 52 }
cache
    [{...,"exports":{"data":{"value":52}},..]}]
{ value: 57 }
cache
    [{...,"exports":{"data":{"value":57}},..]}]
{ value: 62 }
cache
     [{...,"exports":{"data":{"value":62}},..]}]
{ value: 67 }
```

you can see now, that every time the `require` function returns **the cached version of the module**. If it returns the original module, it had to be the original value, not the increased value.